# Equivalent to c:set in thymeleaf

Tags: spring, taglib, thymeleaf

With thymeleaf, is there any any to set a variable like this:

```
<c:set var="index" value="${status.index}"/>
```

this variable is retrieve inside some custom tags I have in my project this way:

```
pageContext.findAttribute("index")
```